# Break at unknown line of code

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2012, user-interface

Is there a way to break at a line of code without knowing where to put the breakpoint?

I often don't know the name of a certain class, but I do know which control in the UI causes the problem. 
So either I need to get the control's name from the UI
or
stop at when a certain event is fired (e.g. a MenuItem is clicked and a Dialog is shown - I want to stop at the event handler or the dialog's constructor).

I know it's possible for HTML pages to hover over parts and see their names. Does VS2012 provide something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You may be need something like :

[UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms727247%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  Which you can use to investigate controls on your windows and event they fire.

Comment: Though that program shows quite a lot information about the overall layout of your application it does not show any information about the types of certain controls. It only seems to know .Net controls but when, for example a DataGridView is derived it still shows DataGridView as the control's type

Comment: @WiiMaxx: I edited my question. Actually I'm using WinForms in this particular case. So snoop is no option for me. Sorry for my inaccuracy

Comment: @TobiasValinski what a pity unfortunately didn't know tools for WForms :(

Comment: @TobiasValinski: at least you can localize your search, on some specific control. you *should* be able also get its name, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may open the Visual Studio IDE and break execution of the code. It will break on the current executing code and will let you debug from there.

Not sure if it will let you reach to any unknown line of code.

Worth giving a try!

Comment: I think in UI app VS will show only at Application.Run() line. At least this happens in the most of my cases

Comment: You're right! But it also depends on the type of debugging. One may also attach to some other process and debug in binary mode. I am not sure how to do it, but I am sure that this is doable by using Visual Studio. So, one can debug inside binary files too.

Comment: Yeah, i just read there is a way to wait for the next event when pausing, stepping in (F11) and causing the event being fired. But that doesn't seem to work with mouse events since the app just keeps running when I clicked the button

Answer (score 0):

You can learn what code is executed after you click a button with [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) or Visual Studio Ultimate [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) and then put the breakpoint at it.